# firebase-admin with typescript in firebase cloud functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am using firebase cloud functions with javascript on cloud functions.
And, I want to switch from javascript to typescript.

However I cannot use firebase-admin on typescript as following command failed.

```
command: npm install @types/firebase-admin --save-dev
error:  '@types/firebase-admin' is not in the npm registry.
```

According to this release note, it looks that firebase admin support typescript.
Can somebody tell us how to use typescript with firebase-admin on cloud functions?

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#4.1.3

Answer (score 29):

You don't need to install an `@types` module, because `firebase-admin` ships with TypeScript support in the box. You should be able to use it with TypeScript just by installing `firebase-admin`.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
```

Answer (score 18):

Another option could be this way.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as serviceAccount from './service-account.json';

const firebaseAdmin = admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as admin.ServiceAccount)
});
```

Answer (score 11):

It seems that types are provided when imported using ES6 Modules:

1. `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": true,               // json imports
        "esModuleInterop": true,                 // import common modules as ES6 Modules
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,    // support typesystem compatibility
    }
}
```

2. `index.ts`

```js
import firebase from 'firebase-admin';
import serviceAccount from './service-account.json';

//snake_case to camelCase
const params = {
    type: serviceAccount.type,
    projectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
    privateKeyId: serviceAccount.private_key_id,
    privateKey: serviceAccount.private_key,
    clientEmail: serviceAccount.client_email,
    clientId: serviceAccount.client_id,
    authUri: serviceAccount.auth_uri,
    tokenUri: serviceAccount.token_uri,
    authProviderX509CertUrl: serviceAccount.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
    clientC509CertUrl: serviceAccount.client_x509_cert_url
}

firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(params),
})
```

Comment: What is the type of `const db = firebase.firestore()`? I can't seem to find a typescript type that works for it anywhere, I've tried `firebase.FirebaseFirestore` and many other things to no avail.

Comment: @NickSweeting Better late than never, but it will be `firebase.firestore.Firestore` (from the import) or `FirebaseFirestore.Firestore` (the global type).

Answer (score 4):

For those who are still struggling, **reloading VSCode** after installing firebase-admin did the work for me.

Comment: `ctrl+shift+p -> restart ts server`  may have the same effect

Comment: How is this possible? I've been struggling for hours..

Answer (score 3):

I know i'm late but I found another way to do this, using the answer given by Peter:

1. tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": true,               // json imports
        "esModuleInterop": true,                 // import common modules as ES6 Modules
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,    // support typesystem compatibility
    }
}
```

2. index.ts

```
import firebase from 'firebase-admin';
import serviceAccount from './service-account.json';

firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount as any), //Cast as any instead of clone the JSON.
})
```

Comment: Using `any` should be discouraged, instead use `as firebase.ServiceAccount`. However, if using Cloud Functions, there is no need to even manually specify a service account, just call `firebase.initializeApp()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { initializeApp, cert } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { getMessaging } from 'firebase-admin/messaging';

const app: App = initializeApp(
  {
    credential: cert('./firebase.json'),
  },
  'appname',
);

class PushNotificationService {
  options = {
    priority: 'high',
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24,
  };
  
  send = (userToken: any, message: any): void => {
      getMessaging(app)
      .sendToDevice(userToken, message, this.options)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      });
  };
}

export default PushNotificationService;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const serviceAccount = require('./firebase.json');

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
}

export const firebaseDB = admin.firestore();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32484482)